# How to make doxygen create "Include dependency graph for ..." only for web pages (not for tex/PDF)?

Tags: c++, linux, graph, documentation, doxygen

So while [SVG is zoomable and browsable](http://195.19.243.13/documentation/html/da/d05/file__service_8h.html) and looks messy, but OK in general:

[image]

`Include dependency graph` [inside PDF file (page 195)](http://195.19.243.13/documentation/cloud_observer_cpp_docs.pdf) looks really as a mess:

[image]

I auto generate my documentatoion [via such script on linux](http://code.google.com/p/cloudobserver/source/browse/trunk/CloudLoader/docs-installer-linux.sh?r=2220) via command like:

```
            doxygen
            cd release/latex/

            pdflatex refman.tex
            makeindex refman.idx
            pdflatex refman.tex
```

That generates HTML and PDF docs for me. How shall I change my [doxygen file](http://code.google.com/p/cloudobserver/source/browse/trunk/CloudServer/documentation/Doxyfile?r=2220) or script in order to have no "Include dependency graph for ..." inside my tex/PDF files, while still having them inside HTML docs?

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't appear to be a mechanism to do this within the Doxygen configuration file, however you could customize the file between two runs of Doxygen to get the behavior your looking for. For example, you could disable both HTML and LATEX generation in the Doxyfile:

```
GENERATE_HTML = NO
GENERATE_LATEX = NO
```

You could then invoke Doxygen twice, once for HTML (with DOT) enabled, and once with LATEX (w/o DOT). In your script this would look something like:

```
( cat Doxyfile ; echo "GENERATE_HTML = YES" ) | doxygen -
( cat Doxyfile ; echo "GENERATE_LATEX = YES" ; echo "HAVE_DOT = NO" ) | doxygen -
```

This will disable all `DOT` based graphics in the tex/PDF output. If you want to include some but not others, you'll need to fine-tune the specific options you want to enable/disable for tex/PDF.

See the [Doxygen FAQ](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/faq.html) for more information about customizing the Doxyfile from the command line.